# Bootcamp error: Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, bootcamp, windows

Whenever I try to proceed with the bootcamp installation or click the download windows support software option from the action menu, it throws me that error.

I've googled this problem and made sure I have a strong wifi connection, plugged in my Macbook while doing this, am running the latest Catalina version and apart from the current windows 10 iso on the microsoft website, tried using older versions of windows 10. Nothing helped.

Comment: Remarkably similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1595334/issue-with-installing-windows-10-on-bootcamp-mbair-2020-catalina-15-0/1595337#1595337 posted 10 minutes earlier

Comment: If you want to try installing without the use of the Boot Camp Assistant, then post the model identifier for your Mac and I will try to provide a link to directly download the Windows Support Software.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I actually found an app from GitHub called Brigadier and used it to download the windows support software, but I can't really do anything with it, I tried putting it in /Library/Applications Support/BootCamp but Boot Camp started downloading the file again when I tried to install windows (and therefore threw me that error again)

Comment: I do not use Brigadier to download the Windows Support Software for your Mac. I basically manually do what Brigadier does. Some older versions of Brigadier, that have not been updated, may download an older version of the Windows Support Software for your Mac. I would post what downloads are available, but I cannot because I have no idea which MacBook you have.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have a MacBookAir 9,1 with the i3 cpu, but I don't get what would I do with the files you'd give me.

Comment: You would need to install Windows without using the Boot Camp Assistant. It would probably be easiest to use a flash drive, but a flash drive could be avoided at a cost of additional steps. My way to acquire the Windows Support Software is given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1595334/getting-a-not-currently-available-error-when-attempting-to-install-windows-10/1595377#1595377). I could try posting the steps to install Windows if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been getting same error when trying to install windows with bootcamp but I managed to bypass it. Usually I would choose win iso image, choose size for windows partition and click next. Software would begin to download but soon after the error would show up. Usually i would click OK and it would cancel installation, but this time i did not click anything and left it for some time and I noticed that download bar is changing. I left it to finish and only then click OK message, and then I re-run bootcamp installation and that worked!